# D2L to our SIS through REST: occasionally the browser gets lost

Tags: desire2learn

Occasionally when we go from the "Export Grades to SIS" link in D2L back to our SIS, using the REST API in our SIS to get the grades from D2L, somewhere in the going back and forth between systems, the browser gets lost and simply goes blank.  I think the problem is happening in the final hand-off from D2L to our SIS--that seems to be the point where the browser loses track of where it is.  When this happens, our SIS continues to act as if it thinks everything is still working correctly--it does pull grades through the REST API, and does everything it is supposed to do.  But the browser session has gone blank, and never shows anything from either D2L or our SIS after that, so the user will not know what is going on.

This happens roughly one out of every 6-8 times we test the link between D2L and our SIS.  I don't see a definite pattern, at least not yet.

Any ideas what we are doing wrong?  What sorts of things should we be looking at to try to determine where the browser is getting lost?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an operational issue with a server it is probably best to open a support ticket with Desire2Learn.